how to run LLava model Cli command in google colab?
I just installed Llava mode on Google Colab, and I just run this code it will give me output result without any error.
file_name = "/content/images/style_name_fix/saamxvr_A_female_teacher_is_teaching_three_cute_little_students_82f49e63-dce9-4d36-83ea-8c0b7d991d96.png"
image, output = caption_image(f'{file_name}', 'Generate Image meta title, description, 30 keyword')
print(output);

But what I want to do is I will upload multiple image in to folder and  above script it will scan all image in folder one processes one by one and giving me out out,
so I wrote this script
file_names = os.listdir('/content/images')
sorted_file_names = sorted(file_names)
for file_name in sorted_file_names:
    try:
        image, output = caption_image(f'/content/images/{file_name}', 'Generate Image meta title, description, 30 keyword.')
        print(output)
        # image
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_name}: {str(e)}")
        continue

But it will show this error:

Error processing style_name_fix: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/content/images/style_name_fix'

Any advice?
